# how to typedef a vector of a custom class?

Tags: c++, stl

I have class T defined and implemented with a default constructor, a copy constructor and an assignment operator overloaded

I have tried to do the following

```
      #include <vector>
      //template <class Board>
      typedef std::vector<Board> t_bvector;
```

with and without the comment, I am getting this error

```
../Piece.H:143:1: error: ‘t_bvector’ does not name a type
In file included from ../Board.C:1:0:
../Board.H:14:1: error: template declaration of ‘typedef’
In file included from ../Board.C:1:0:
```

I dont have C++11, and want to retain basic vector methods like .insert, .size
is there a way to solve it? or a better suggestion for an STL container ?

Comment: is it able to use common vector methods? like .insert, .size ?

Comment: It's not at all clear what you're trying to do and what the problem is. I'm not even convinced that the duplicate is relevant.

Comment: maybe you need forward declaring Board class ?!

Comment: Hi, forward decaring isnt needed because I am writing this in the same file as the class
what i want to do is simple - just declare a vector of my custom class

Comment: Doesn't matter if it's in the same file if the denifition comes after the typedef. It's not clear in you question if that's the case. And no you don't add template before the typedef

Comment: @YNWA, Is `Board` a class or a class template. From the commented out line in your posted code, it appears like it is a class template.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure what you're trying to do with that `template <class Board>` part but I'm guessing you've got some syntax wrong in your actual code or something misplaced.

Here is an example of how you should be trying to setup such a typedef.

```
#include <vector>

class Board
{
public:
    int foo;
};

typedef std::vector<Board> t_bvector;
```

---

EDIT

Now that you've explained a bit more:

```
class Board;
typedef std::vector<Board> t_bvector;

class Board
{
public:
    t_bvector SomeFunction();
};
```

Comment: hi, tis removes one error and adds a another. I want to use the new vector as a return for a Board method. ive tried using a forward decleration but didnt solve it, tried placing it after the class decleration also...any tips?

Comment: @YNWA Then update your question with more of the actual code you've tried and the resulting error. I can't really guess what you've got, but I know my example works on its own.

Comment: Forward declare Board, i.e. add class Board; before the typedef. And move those before the Board class definition

Comment: hi, this solved some of the problems. but now I am having problems with uses of this new type in other files (that includes the .H with the class) error from other file - "error: ‘t_bvector’ does not name a type".
posting the code - i can but its pretty long...very long